# force tgp to use a zero mean GP prior

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, gaussian-process

I'm using the `tgp` package in R for fully Bayesian Gaussian Process Regression, and it's great! I'm currently performing regression for experimental data coming from turbomachinery testing, and I'm using the `bgp` function. This function uses a GP prior with either a `linear` mean or a `constant` mean (respectively, option `meanfn="linear"` or `meanfn="constant"`, which is the default). Note that `tgp` allows the use of treed Gaussian priors, but for now I'm staying simple, so I'm using the `bgp` function which doesn't use regression trees, just ordinary Gaussian Processes.

I would like my posterior predictive mean to go to zero away from the training set data, for physical reasons. How can I impose that? I was thinking to set the prior over $\beta_0$ to a Normal distribution centered at 0 and with an extremely small variance, but I'm not sure how to do that. From `help(btgp)`

```
bprior Linear (beta) prior, default is "bflat"; alternates include "b0" hierarchical Normal
prior, "bmle" empirical Bayes Normal prior, "b0not" Bayesian treed LMstyle
prior from Chipman et al. (same as "b0" but without tau2), "bmzt" a independent
Normal prior (mean zero) with inverse-gamma variance (tau2), and
"bmznot" is the same as "bmznot" without tau2. The default "bflat" gives
an “improper” prior which can perform badly when the signal-to-noise ratio is
low. In these cases the “proper” hierarchical specification "b0" or independent
"bmzt" or "bmznot" priors may perform better
```

Default is the improper prior `"bflat"`, which is not what I want. If I use the `"b0"` hierarchical Normal prior, I guess I cannot set the mean and the variance because they should become additional hyperparameters to be determined in the Bayesian paradigm. Thus, I may go for `"bmzt"`, the independent Normal prior with zero mean. However, with this prior I cannot set the variance, which is again an hyperparameter. Basically, I want my prior mean function to be zero, so that away from the data, also the posterior predictive mean will be zero. Is there a way to achieve that?

EDIT: nobody wants to have a try? :) As my actual case is quite complicated, I wrote a small test case which illustrates the main problem, with the help of the `tgp` package author. NOTE: unless you have an optimized version of R, you may want to set `BTE = c(1000,10000,2)` in the call to `bgp`, or you may have to wait for a very long time to get an answer.

```
# clear the workspace
rm(list=ls())
gc()
graphics.off()

# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(825)

# load required packages
library(tgp)
library(ggplot2)

# simulated data
x <- seq(-1,1,len=100)
eps <- rnorm(n=100,mean=0,sd=0.5)
y <- -5*x^2+eps
ymean <- mean(y)

# prediction points
xpred <- seq(-20,20,len=100)

# fit GP
GPModel <- bgp(X=x,Z=y,XX=xpred,meanfn = "constant", bprior="bmzt", 
BTE = c(2000,52000,2), tau2.p=c(1,10000), tau2.lam="fixed")    
ypred <- GPModel$ZZ.mean 

# plots
ymean_vector <- rep(ymean,100)
df <- data.frame(x,y,xpred,ypred,ymean_vector)
p <- ggplot(data=df)
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=xpred,y=ypred),col="blue") +
    geom_line(aes(x=xpred,y=ymean_vector),col="red") +
    geom_line(aes(x=xpred,y=GPModel$ZZ.q1), col="green") + 
    geom_line(aes(x=xpred,y=GPModel$ZZ.q2), col="green")
p
```

The resulting plot is

[image]

The mean response is the red line: the blue line is the GP posterior predictive mean, and the green lines give the 90% credible interval.Thus, outside the training data range, the data mean is indeed included in the 90% credible interval, but I would like the predictive mean to converge to it...I think that if I could find a way to set the standard deviation of the prior for $\beta_0$ to some  extremely small value, I would achieve what I want, but I don't know how to do it.

EDIT2: I can use either a multiplicative (separable) squared exponential kernel
or an additive squared exponential kernel.

```
sep_Gaussian_Kernel <- function(x,y,sigma,l) {
    prod(sigma*exp(-0.5*(abs(x-y)/l)^2))
}    

add_Gaussian_Kernel <- function(x,y,sigma,l) {
    sum(sigma*exp(-0.5*(abs(x-y)/l)^2))/length(x)
}
```

Comment: A fully Bayesian model over which you want fine-grained control to tinker with the model specification? It sounds like you'd be interested in using stan.

Comment: Probably! What's stan? `install.packages("stan")` tells me there's no `stan` package. I'd really like an R solution, though. It has been already quite a pain to wrangle my data and import them in R, I'd rather not export them and import them in some other environment, unless there's really no other way...

Comment: Stan is multi-platform. Try `install.packages("rstan")` ;-) or visit www.mc-stan.org.

Comment: will do, thanks! Hope it doesn't have a steep learning curve ;) any chance you could redo my example in `rstan`? That would be a great way for me to learn, and it would help me tackle my actual problem, which is of course more complex than the one shown here.

Comment: thanks! That would be fantastic :) either multiplicative squared exponential or additive squared exponential would do. In my example they make no difference because there's just one predictor, but in the real case I have more. I'm adding their definition in my question.

Comment: Actually, there are example implementations in the Gaussian Process chapter of the Stan documentation, with code on Github.